# How to import export default funtion with parameter in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to import "render3D.js" export default function in "furniture.js" file with es. I import function "render3D" but I am getting error like render3D is not function".

I have to pass parameter in render3D function. How can i do that?

render3D.js

```
import GLTFLoader from 'three-gltf-loader';
import * as Three from 'three';
import {ObjectLoader} from "three";

let cachedModelJson = null;

export default function(modelPath) {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    let lod = new Three.LOD();

    loader.load(modelPath, function (gltf) {
      let meshArr = [];
      let matArr = [];
      var mergedGeo = new Three.Geometry();


  return Promise.resolve(lod);
}
```

furniture.js

```
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import render2D from './render-utils/render2D.js';
import render3D from './render-utils/render3D.js';

const data = {
    Zuo100703: {
        name: "chair",
        prototype: "items",
        info: {
            title: "California Corner Chair",
            tag: ['furnishing', 'chair', 'zuomod', 'cotton linen'],
            description: "California Corner Chair",
            image: require("./items/zuomod/chair-100703/chair.jpg"),
            rsModel: "scenes/sofa.mi"
        },
        properties: {
            altitude: {
                label: "Altitude",
                type: "length-measure",
                defaultValue: {
                    length: 0
                }
            }
        },
        render2D: render2D,
        render3D: render3D(require("./items/zuomod/chair-100703/100703.gltf"))
    }
}

export default data;
```

Comment: `import render3D from './render-utils/render3D.js';` since render3D is a default export, you don't need to wrap it within `{}`

Comment: Ok It is also not working without wrap

Comment: What error do you get, also do you have a correct file path

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri If I put render3D code is in furniture.js file then it is working otherwise i get error : 'render3D is not a function'